# AWS Kinesis concatenting fields on aggregation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-analytics

When using AWS Kinesis data analytics, is it possible to concatenate a field from the input rows when aggregating events in a [stagger window](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/stagger-window-concepts.html) into a single output row? And if so how can we go about implementing this concatenation during the aggregation? I can’t seem to find examples of this use case in Kinesis so I’m not even sure if this is possible or even an anti-pattern.

For example the input rows for the aggregation looks like the following:
[image]

And the resulting output rows should be (if the stagger window is 1 min) on aggregation concatenating on the USER field:
[image]

Thanks!